# Setting the location of a variable in a list to another variable - python

Tags: python

```
alpha = ["A", "B", "C"]
morsecode = ["*-", "-***", "-*-*"]

string = raw_input(">> ")
list1 = list(string)

a1 = list1[0]

try:
   if a1 in alpha:
        a11 = alpha.index(a1)
        b1 = morsecode.index(a11)
        a1 = b1
        print a1
```

i want you to be able to type in "A" and it will print "*-"

Comment: Why don't you just use a dictionary? Make "alpha" the key, and "morsecode" the value.

Comment: See the answer by iCodez. This is a very straight forward implementation of a dictionary. I suggest you read some introductory Python text as this is a very fundamental data structure.

Answer (score 1):

> i want you to be able to type in "A" and it will print "*-"

What you want to do can be accomplished quite easily with a [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
>>> dct = {
...     "A" : "*-", 
...     "B" : "-***", 
...     "C" : "-*-*"
... }
>>> string = raw_input(">> ")
>> A
>>> print dct[string]
*-
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think OP wants to handle more than a single character as input:

```
morse_code_dict = {"A": "*-", "B": "-***", "C": "-*-*"}

string = raw_input(">> ")

for char in string:
    print morse_code_dict[char],
```

Comment: Yeah i trying to make a program that changes english into morse code

Comment: The above should do that

Comment: it says the : is invalid syntax

Comment: oh wait i used [ instead of {

Comment: ok it works now, but is there a way to print it all on the same line?

Comment: See the edit. Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-in-python-without-newline-or-space

Comment: oh wait... were the parentheses supposed to print it on one line

Comment: Try that, with just the comma at the end

Answer (score 0):

I agree that a dictionary is the proper data structure for this.

I you *want* to use a list, you could do something along these lines:

```
morsecode = ["*-", "-***", "-*-*"]

ch = raw_input(">> ")

try:
    print '"{}" in morses code:"{}"'.format(ch, morsecode[ord(ch)-ord('A')])
except IndexError:
    print 'no code for: "{}"'.format(ch)
```